# Trouble Accessing Values in Received Object in Swift

Tags: swift

I was successfully able to receive an object using WKScriptMessage but am having trouble unpacking an object I sent over.

For the following code:

```
if let sites:NSObject = message.body["sites"] as NSObject! {
    println(site)
}
```

I successfully get:

```
{
    blogname = "Site 1";
    siteurl = "http://one.example.com";
},
{
    blogname = "Site 2";
    siteurl = "http://two.example.com";
},
{
    blogname = "Site 3";
    siteurl = "http://three.example.com";
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here. How would I access `blogname`and `siteurl`?

Edit: Clearly, I should be using Dictionary, but I'm having trouble casting it.

Comment: Well, what are they? If they are dictionaries you need to _say_ so. You are saying they are an NSObject so that's all the compiler knows. And it's right; an NSObject _doesn't_ have a `blogname`. So why are you surprised?

Comment: Thanks for your helpful note, I clarified the question.

Comment: "But I'm having trouble casting it" - how to express a dictionary type: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_dictionary

Comment: Thanks, I'll read that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an array of dictionaries. You should conditionally cast (`as?`) it to a typed array of dictionaries (`[[String : String]]`) instead of `NSObject`.

Then you can access `sites[0]["blogname"]`, for example.

Comment: Thank you! That did it. I appreciate your patience with my obvious beginner's knowledge of the subject.